# Reactive Form Array For Check Boxes In Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have an array of products that I return on an object these look like:

```
{"opportunityId":2, "customer":"Graham's Motors",..."products":[{"id":1,"name":"Optoin 1","selected":false},{"id":2,"name":"Option 2","selected":false},{"id":3,"name":"Option 3","selected":true},...
```

I have a typescript file that imports:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
```

and I create a FormGroup like this:

```
opportunityForm = new FormGroup({
    partner: new FormControl(''),
    customer: new FormControl(''),
    ...
    products: new FormArray([])
```

I am using an API call to populate the data when it is fetched like this:

```
this.dataService.getOpportunity(this.id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.opportunityForm.setValue({
      partner: data.partner ?? '',
      customer: data.customer ?? '',
      ...
      });
    data.products.forEach(product => {
      (<FormArray>this.opportunityForm.get('products')).push(new FormControl(product));
    });
```

which I think is correctly putting the products in as a form array. My problem seems to be how to construct the html. Currently it looks like:

```
<div class="col" formArrayName="products">
  <div *ngFor="let option of products; index as i" >
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        name="option.name"
        value="{{option.value}}" 
        [formControlName]="i"                                       
        [checked]="option.selected"
        (change)="option.selected = !option.selected"/>
      {{option.name}}
    </label>
  </div>   
</div>
```

I get an error that:

ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'products'.

But I can't see what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help. I just want to show a list of check boxes with if they have been selected already (there's an edit form) and then allow the user to update them before they post the form back.

Comment: by a quick look I would say `formArrayName="products"` sould be `formArrayName="opportunityForm.products" `

Comment: thanks, but just gives me: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'opportunityForm.products'

Comment: don't you have a `opportunityForm` class member in your component ?

Comment: just the reference to the FormGroup as per the code above

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your form a class member of your component:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  opportunityForm;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.opportunityForm = new FormGroup({
          partner: new FormControl(''),
          customer: new FormControl(''),
          products: new FormArray([])
        });
      }
}
```

then you access it via your template:

```
  <div class="col" formArrayName="opportunityForm.products">
  <div *ngFor="let option of opportunityForm.products; index as i" >
  ....
```

Comment: I have the code exactly as yours and I get two errors: Cannot find control with name: 'opportunityForm.products' and Must supply a value for form control with name: 'products'.